# Composable lambdas: are they created on each recomposition, are there some clever optimizations?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In this snippet

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Toolbar(content: @Composable () -> Unit) { ... }

fun slotBuilder(text: String): @Composable () -> Unit { 
  return { Text(text) } 
}

@Composable
fun Screen() {
  Toolbar { Text("hello") } // A
  Toolbar(content = slotBuilder("hello")) // B
}
```

Is `A` and `B` equivalent allocation-wise? In each case a new lambda will be created on each recomposition (function call) of the `Screen()` or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In case A, a new lambda is created on each recomposition of Screen, beacause it is an inline function.

In case B, the lambda is created once during the initial call to slotBuilder and is reused on subsequent recompositions of Screen.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct: slotBuilder is called on each recomposition, why would lambda be reused, where will it be stored?